# Infinite loop formed while calling a function from a template class,Please anybody explain

Tags: c++

Here is a code which will not run properly,but if we use this function as 
a standalone template function.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
int z=10;
template <class T>class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {

            cout<<"A constructor\n";
        }
        int z;
        T sort_rishi_fun(T arr[]);
};
template <class T>T A <T>::sort_rishi_fun( T arr[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<z;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<z;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j+1]<arr[j])
            {
                T temp;
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int z=10;
    int arr[100]; 
    cout << "\nEnter the number you wanted to be sort\n" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<z;i++)
    {
        cout<<"::insert the value at"<<i<<"th location::";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout<<"you have inserted this\n";
    for(int i=0;i<=z;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
    A<int> a;
    a.sort_rishi_fun(arr)
        for(int i=0;i<=z;i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

If we use this function as a standalone template function then it will work.But It will create an infinite loop now.Explain anyone pls.

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables z, one global and another one inside the class. You only initialize the global one. Inside the class, the class variable is used and this is not initialized. That is why it works when it is a global method, but doesn't work when it is a class template method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell you never seem to initialize `z` in your `class A`.

try

```
template <class T>class A
{
  public:

  A(int z_):z(z_)
  {

    cout<<"A constructor\n";
  }
  int z;
  T sort_rishi_fun(T arr[]);
};

// then in main()
A<int> a(z);
```